# Placing Infinite condition in c

Tags: c, infinite-loop

I am running a C program with an infinite `for` loop:

```
for(;;)
{
    //Statement
}
```

Why is it running an infinite number times, even though we have not specified the loop's initialization, condition and incrementation?

What do the "blank" values mean?

Comment: All three are optional.  No condition -> keeps running.

Comment: I did a quick search, and this question doesn't appear to me to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

Here's the basic syntax of a for loop.

```
for(clause-1; expression-2; expression-3) statement;
```

According to *The C Programming Language* by K&R, both clause-1 and expression-3 can be omitted. An omitted expression-2 is replaced by a non-zero constant. And as we know, any non-zero value means "true" in C.

P.S.: Though the K&R book is quite outdated, it's considered as the Bible of C by many.

Answer (score 5):

The loop only breaks when the condition is `false`. Since there is no condition, nothing can be false, and the loop doesn't break.

Comment: Relevant standardese: "*Both clause-1 and expression-3 can be omitted. An omitted expression-2 is replaced by a nonzero constant.*".

Comment: similar to how `while ( 1 ) { // do stuff }` will also produce an infinite loop, because `1` gets evaluated to `1`, always, which is true. (basically a no-op test condition)

Answer (score 2):

the `for(;;)` statement is the same as the `while`. If you "convert" the `for(;;)` it will be something like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

to this

```
i = 0;
while( i < n )
{
    //Do stuff
    i++;
}
```

So if the middle statement has nothing in it, it will run forever

EDIT:

In the third part of the loop you can do anything. You could even to this:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++, /*Do stuff*/){}
```

Comment: Similar, but different: Should `Do stuff` have a `continue`, `i` is not incremented in the `while()` loop, but `i` is incremented in `for()` loop.